# Prove that $(D(K), \| \cdot\|_D)$ is a Banach space

Tags: real-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

Let $K$ be a metric space. Denote $\mathcal{B_1}(K)$ as the class of real-valued bounded first Baire functions on $K$. A real-valued function $f:K \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the first Baire function if there exists a sequence of continuous functions that converges pointwise to $f.$

Let

$D(K) = \{ f \in \mathcal{B_1}(K): f = u - v, \text{ where } u,v \geq 0 \text{ are bounded and lower semicontinuous functions.} \}$

Define a norm $\| f \|_D = \inf \{ \| u + v \|_{\infty}: f = u -v \text{ for }u, v \geq 0, \text{ bounded and lower semicontinuous functions.} \}$, where $\| f \|_{\infty} = \sup_{x \in K} f(x)$

Question: How to prove that $(D(K), \| \cdot\|_D)$ is a Banach space?

My attempt: I want to show that if $\sum \| f_n \|_D$ converges, then $\sum f_n$ converges. Hence $(D(K), \| \cdot \|_D$ is a Banach space.

Suppose $\sum \|f_n\|_D$ converges. By definition of $\| \cdot \|_D,$ there exists $u_n$ and $v_n$ such that $\sum \|f_n\|_D = \sum \| u_n + v_n \|_{\infty}$. Then I stuck here. Any hint on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Comment: A space needs to satisfy a bunch of conditions in order to be Banach. It would help if you specified what you managed to prove on your own and what you did not.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval: I have included my working in the post.

Comment: In the definition of the norm, you have used the L infinity norm. How is that defined here? What is the underlying measure on your metric space K? Or do you want to replace the L infinity norm by the sup?

Comment: @Siddhant The definition $\|f\|_\infty:=\sup_{x\in X}|f(x)|$ for a bounded continuous function $f$ on a topological space $X$ is fairly standard. Obviously the use of $\infty$ is borrowed from measure theory but it is clear in context what is meant.

Comment: But in the question as stated, f need not be a continuous function. As the pointwise limit of continuous functions need not be continuous. The use of $\infty$ is for lower semi continuous and not for continuous functions and so it is not clear to me what is the precise norm that you are using